# If then in Power BI DAX statement

Tags: powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

A TRANSACTION table includes column TRANSACTIONPAYERID, which is the ID of the payer associated with the transaction. Wherever TRANSACTIONPAYERID is NULL, the financial class should be “SELF-PAY”.  Please implement a solution so that these transactions are categorized correctly in any analysis by financial class.

Answer below but doesn't work

```
Measure 1 = 
VAR Transaction = SELECTEDVALUE('NULL'[TransactionPayerID]
RETURN
VAR Transaction = SelectedValue('SelfPay'[TransactionType]
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECTEDVALUE doesn't work that way. A good overview is [here](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-the-selectedvalue-function-in-dax/).
Assuming that your table is called 'Transaction', it might be best to create a new column
For a calculated column it would be:

```
New Column = IF('Transaction'[TranactionPayerID] = BLANK(), "Self-pay", 'Transaction'[TranactionPayerID])
```

Comment: the financial class is coming from the same table called transaction but is called transaction type. So basically transaction type has the value Self-Pay. When the transaction payer id is null then transaction type should be self pay. How do you correct for that @Jonee